# Stopping Cmatrix command with EOF

Tags: bash, eof, interactive, kill-process, qgenericmatrix

I am trying to run cmatrix for a couple of seconds inside a bash program, cmatrix quits with the `q` keystroke. I tried passing commands into it using EOF, but it seems to stop after one milisecond? Here is the code

```
cmatrix << EOF
sleep 3
echo "q"
EOF
```

I have also tried this to no avail:

```
cmatrix << EOF
PID=$?
sleep 3
kill $PID #or kill -TERM $PID
EOF
```

Comment: With the latter code, the program doesn't stop at all

Comment: Both of these send all your commands as *input* to cmatrix. It's unlikely that it expects a command like `sleep 3`. For your second attempt, you could just run cmatrix in the background with `cmatrix &` and then run your commands, no here-doc required.